# EmberJS/handlebars how to add a class to every other tag in each loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I currently have some markup that looks like the following in my Ember.js app that uses Handlebars for templating:

```
 {{#each block in controller.gameBlocks}}
        <div class="row-fluid">
            {{#each game in block.games}}
                <div class="span6 span6_first-child">
         ... more stuff ...
 {{/#each}}
```

The problem I have here is I don't want to include the class `span6_first-child` in every other iteration of the each statement above or every even numbered index number if we were to have an `each_with_index` type loop. Is this trivial to do with handlebars/ember.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that class and apply it's css rules to a new selector using pseudo selectors. As far as I know, there's no constructs for even/odd/every other built into handlebars.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
            {{#each game in block.games}}
                <div class="span6">
         ... more stuff ...


.row-fluid .span6:nth-child(odd) {
 /* Prior rules here */
}
```

Comment: I had to use .span6:nth-child(odd) but your answer definitely pointed me in the correct way of solving this. Thank you.

Comment: Whoops, totally forgot that extra part. Edited. Glad you got it working out!